# Main Site Navigation Clashes with Blog Script CSS

Tags: css, navigation, blogs

At [www.test.webitry.net](http://www.test.webitry.net) is a a main site navigation and header that I have installed onto a blog script so as to integrate it with the main site. The main site navigation is being snagged by a white line passing through the links and it is is also impacting on the rollover. See image attached.[image]

What could be causing this clash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a break tag (<br style="clear:both" />) inside the ordered list tag (<ol>) that's malformed HTML and should not be done. The only tags which should be inside an <ol> tags are <li> tags.

Try removing the border-bottom here as well...

```
.nav ol {
list-style: none;
width: 950px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
padding: 0;        /* <----- you can also remove this line since it's a duplicate */
background-color: #3b3b44;
border-top: 1px solid #ccf;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccf;  /* <---- remove this line    */
}
```

If you don't want the white line, it shouldn't be in the CSS.

In addition, you have all links styled with a border on the bottom, you may need to specifically set that attribute for the navigation links so the general anchor properties are not "picked up".

```
.nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 2px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff; 
border-right: 1px solid #ccf; 
border-bottom: none;  /* <------------ add this line */
}
```

Comment: I note what you say. I tried removing same and site falls apart! The break tag thing (<br style="clear:both" />) was installed to solve a problem that was detailed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392054/installing-existing-site-navigation-into-blog-script So for the moment the thing is doing a job.......

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to `.nav ol` and delete the `<br/>` tag.

Comment: The advice you got to add that break tag was bad advice. It's malformed HTML and shouldn't be used. If your site "falls apart" without it, you need to rethink construction. It's a simply thing to wrap your navigation in a div, then add a clear:both style below the ordered list. That way your HTML is correctly formatted.

Comment: Thanks Scott the <br/> tag thing is now removed and replaced with My Head Hurts recommended overflow: hidden in the .nav ol. Site holds together now with that introduced correction change. Silly white line problem remains in place on the navigation. !!

Comment: I've added to the answer above. I assumed you wanted the white line for some reason since it's present in the CSS. If you don't want the white line at all, simply remove it from the CSS.

Comment: Cant remember why that line was there. Removed and line still exists. See comparison with main site navigation at www.tuirtre.webitry.net

Comment: Should have gone to specsavers! Double entry removed. Nav still works the same.